# Launch File Upload from Visualforce Page

Tags: files

I'm trying to figure out how I can add a button to my visualforce page that will open the same file upload box that you get when you click contribute from the library tab.  I also want to link that file to the record for the page that launches the upload process.  Any help would be greatly appreciate!
Thanks!

Fred

The out of the box functionality I'm looking to replicate is the same as when you click the contribute.  The main point would be to use out of the box rather than building a page to do this.  The below two screenshots are what you get:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the "box" you want to use?

Comment: I've updated my post with the screenshot.  thanks again!

Comment: Yea I was hoping it was something else, but I think my first answer remains the same, since they are pop-ups we can't use URL hacks to replicate the behavior. The only other option would be to try to cheat salesforce and create a button that calls the same script that the standard button does but that will only work if you can gaurantee the script is imported.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I can still link to the files page where they can upload. Just adds another step.